# How to delete selected HTML element interactively in IE's developer tools?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, ie-developer-tools

I can delete html elements interactively in Firebug and Chrome's Developer Tools. How can I do the same in IE 9's Developer Tools? I see options to copy only.

I tried FireBug Lite but there weren't any options to do any action on any selected HTML element.

Any other options which work in IE?

Answer (score 12):

With IE Developer tools, you need to go to `Edit` mode (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> or click the toolbar button with the pen icon) and remove the element from HTML by manually altering the markup. There is no handy right click delete functionality.

Comment: This is really ugly. I have to search for the tag and there's no easy way to find the closing tag and delete in between.

Comment: Agree with you. IE 9 dev tools have a long way to cacth up with Firebug or Chrome Dev Tools